# Support for WebView

Tags: webview, video.js

Does video.js support Android WebView?

We use an Android app to put a tablet in Kiosk Mode in which our web app runs. However, webview video tag does not give us a image of the first frame, only the ugly widgets background.

Answer (score 0):

A better question might be whether your WebView supports video.js. You need to configure the WebView to behave equivalently to a proper browser – HTML5 video definitely won't work without some tweaking. I've found this custom web view to work well (including with video.js):

https://code.google.com/p/html5webview/